# Visualizing two variables which have a very similar values

Tags: data-visualization, multivariate-analysis, dataset, data-mining, descriptive-statistics

I have two columns of data, and would like to show their differences through the visualization approach. The current issue is that these two columns are in-fact very close to each other. In other words, I would like to zoom in the minor differences that are existed using a graphical way. Are there any suggestions? Thanks.

Here is part of the data set.  The third column is the difference between the first column and second column.

```
0.999998295 0.999998331 -3.56E-08
0.99999381  0.999986678 7.13E-06
0.999997682 0.999998494 -8.12E-07
0.999989429 0.999989062 3.67E-07
0.999998877 0.999998505 3.72E-07
0.999995327 0.999996709 -1.38E-06
0.999995779 0.999995146 6.33E-07
0.999997484 0.999996701 7.83E-07
0.999998829 0.999998076 7.53E-07
0.999997523 0.999998836 -1.31E-06
0.999998287 0.999996964 1.32E-06
0.999983543 0.999989135 -5.59E-06
0.999992705 0.999994249 -1.54E-06
0.999995663 0.999998168 -2.50E-06
0.999997263 0.999999195 -1.93E-06
0.999994474 0.999996713 -2.24E-06
0.999993058 0.999994063 -1.00E-06
0.999998295 0.999996262 2.03E-06
0.99999736  0.999998185 -8.25E-07
0.999983507 0.996875105 0.003108402
0.999996339 0.999996597 -2.58E-07
```

Comment: I do not understand the problem. What do you mean by zoom ?

Comment: Depends on what makes sense and what you want to show/know about your data; you can try subtracting mean (column-wise, row-wise, global), show differences or quotients, also in function of one or other variable, subtract this data from one (and maybe use log scale), draw scatterplot...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visualizing items of very different scales is difficult. Here you have 3 scales: values around 1.0, values around 1e-7 and a single value at 3e-3. If you're trying to present the data in a single visual, two graphs would be better than trying to play tricks with the axes.

[image: All data][image: zoomed in view]

If order is not important, an X by Y scatter plot may work better.

[image: all data][image: zoomed in view]

Comment: I concur, there's one point that is just not like the others, (0.999983507 0.996875105).  The difference in y-value from that one  dwarfs the differences amongst the other points.

Answer (score 1):

As @mbq mentions, using a log scale might work, and is possibly the commonest way of including items of very different scales on the same chart. (The charts below actually plot $log (1 - x)$ where the $x$s are the values in the first two columns, with the axis labels altered to match the original scale.)

But just bear in mind how misleading these might be for an audience not used to seeing them - they emphasise differences in values approaching 1 and de-emphasise differences in smaller values. (I imagine that's why @xan recommends two separate charts.)

[image: line chart][image: scatter chart]